# How/Why is imagedata stored as char - OpenCV

Tags: c, pointers, image-processing, types, opencv

I'm a tad confused.

I am just getting started with OpenCV and its image data is pointed to by a char pointer.  I can't quite work out how that works considering the actual data itself could be any number of data types, e.g. uint, float, double.  As far as I knew, a pointer had to be of the same type as the pointer it represents.

It's probably worth noting that openCV is a C library and my background is C++, so I am unaware of how these problems of needing variable types are solved in C.

For example the follwing code taken from Learning OpenCV illustrates my confusion:

```
void saturate_sv( IplImage* img ) {
    for( int y=0; y<img->height; y++ ) {
    uchar* ptr = (uchar*) (
    img->imageData + y * img->widthStep
    );
       for( int x=0; x<img->width; x++ ) {
           ptr[3*x+1] = 255;
           ptr[3*x+2] = 255;
       }
    }
}
```

So this works, but when I try to operate on a iplImage of type IPL_DEPTH_64F and use ptr[3*x+1] = 1 The results are incorrect.  So to distil my problems: how can I work on integer or floating point data through char pointers and specifically how could I rectify the above example to work with a double precision data.

Thanks

Comment: Char behaves the same as int in C/C++ (except for being smaller).  Since it doesn't have a byte (8 bit) data type char is used.  I don't know about the other issue so I will just leave this comment.

Comment: Ok, I'm slightly confused as to what you want to achieve: do you want to set the pixel of every row in the image to `255` or set every 2nd,3rd `(3*0+1, 3*0+2)` and then 5th,6th `(3*1+1, 3*1+2)` etc. pixel in the row to `255`?

Comment: that is just an example problem, the function of the code isn't really important.  What is important is using floating or double data which should range from 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 255.  And conceptually how is a char pointer used to modify integer or floating point data.

Comment: @alifeofzen, how do you know that "the results are incorrect"? OpenCV highgui does not a good work on showing float images like IPL_DEPTH_64. In my projects, I use Python's matplotlib plotting tools to display this double precision data images.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. `IPL_DEPTH_64F` or `double` images will take care of the data from 0 - 1.
2. If you're used to C++ you should check out [OpenCV2.0](http://opencv.org) which has several C++ classes and most importantly, one class, i.e. `Mat` to handle images, matrices, etc.

Here's a simple way to access elements in your image efficiently:

```
IplImage* img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(300,300),IPL_DEPTH_64F,1);
for( int y=0; y<img->height; y++ ) 
    {
       double* ptr = reinterpret_cast<double*>(img->imageData + y * img->widthStep);
       for( int x=0; x<img->width; x++ ) 
       {
          ptr[x] = double(255);
       }
    }
cvNamedWindow("SO");
cvShowImage("SO",img);
cvWaitKey();
cvDestroyAllWindows();
cvReleaseImage(&img);
```

Since you're working with a `double` image, it makes more sense to:

1. Work with a `double` pointer so you can easily assign elements in a row with `ptr[x]`
2. Do the pointer arithmetic in bytes (`img->imageData + y * img->widthStep`) and the cast it to a `double` pointer

Also, it's **important** that you do the pointer arithmetic in bytes (or `uchar`, i.e. `unsigned char`) since **OpenCV tends to pad the rows of the images** with extra bytes for efficiency (especially for `double` images).

So even if a `double` element is 8 bytes, and you have, say, 300 rows, a row is not guaranteed to end at 8*300 or 2400 bytes since OpenCV might pad the end.

Therefore, this prevents you from initializing a pointer to the first element of the image and then using `ptr[y*img->height+x]` to access elements since each row might have more than `8*(y*img->height)` bytes.

**That's** why the example code calculates the pointer to each row each time using `img->widthStep` which represents the true size of each row in bytes.

**OpenCV 2.0**

If you use the `Mat` class, you can do the same thing along these lines:

```
cv::Mat img(300,300,CV_64FC1);
for( int y=0; y<img.rows; y++ ) 
    {
       double* ptr = reinterpret_cast<double*>(img.data + y * img.step);
       for( int x=0; x<img.cols; x++ ) 
       {
          ptr[x] = double(255);
       } 
    }
cv::namedWindow("SO");
cv::imshow("SO",img);
cv::waitKey();
```

where img.step is the distance between successive rows in bytes

And if you want to directly access the element (slower):

`img.at<double>(y,x)`

Comment: Thanks a great deal!  Is there any documentation of the Mat class?

Comment: Sure, if you download the latest version of OpenCV, they've included a detailed manual in http://opencvlibrary.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opencvlibrary/trunk/opencv/doc/opencv.pdf?revision=2261

Comment: With cv::Mat from OpenCV 2.x, I would just mention the existence of cv::Mat::ptr<type>(int row), where you get a pointer of the desired type without hving to do the reinterpret_cast and the bytes arithmetic by yourself.