# OPENCV: can IplImage* hold double value???

Tags: opencv, double, iplimage

I have to create an image to hold double value (that is `-0.0001` or `0.005`).
I've used

```
IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
```

but it doesn't work well. Have you some good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as it should, though you cannot visualize `32F` image, you have to convert it to the `8U`. See [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html?highlight=32f#primitive-operations). BTW, the const is called [`CV_32F` now](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth).

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. I tried to display its value using std::cout<<(double)((char*)(temp->imageData + temp->widthStep*j))[i] insert into a for loop but it doesn't show me double values. Where is the problem?

Comment: Use `img.at<float>(i, j)`. Also, `32F` is `float`, not `double`. You can find everything about pixel data access in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735135/187663).

Comment: The problem is that I'm using IplImage object and not a Mat one. Is it the same ????

Comment: Yes, it is the same in OpenCV2/C++ bindings. Which version and language do you use?

Comment: I'm working on openCV 2.4.0 installed into visual studio 2010. i could use c++ Mat but I wanted to use only c language so I used IplImage.

Comment: I understand you are a very well user so can you explain how to modify my code such that I can save double values into an image and access it into a for loop to show values on command window maybe with std::cout ?

Comment: in this case access pixel like `((float*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*j))[i]`

Comment: I used ((double*)... and it's working fine. Thank you very much...I will post other questions here if you can help me, ok?

Comment: Sure, accept this answer and read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). I or another user will try to help you.

Comment: cvConvertScale(temp_XY,temp_Gaussxy,(1.0/(2.0*PIGRECO*(sigma*sigma*sigma*sigma*sigma*sigma))),0);   can I modify sigma*sigma in a better way??? (such as sigma^6 or exp(sigma,6))

Comment: There is [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/) function in `math.h` (`cmath` in cxx).

Comment: I've come back to you with the last question (I hope): how can I create an array of pointers to IplImage in such a way that it can hold IPL_DEPTH_64F images?

Comment: `IplImage *array = (IplImage *)malloc(imgCount * sizeof(IplImage *));` `IplImage` is polymorphic in dynamic way, it holds image type information inside.

Comment: I created it like this: IplImage** ALL = new IplImage*[5]; is different from your way ? In your way I didn't understand imgCount what it is.

Comment: My bad, there should have been double pointers. Anyway, your method is appropriate.

Comment: okay... I have to implement this tmp = sqrt((Dxx - Dyy).^2 + 4*Dxy.^2); where Dxx are images. How do you do sqrt????

Comment: please search the [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=sqrt#cv.Sqrt)