# OpenCV Image data type conversion in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to convert an Image data from char to double in C++, for example

```
Mat img = imread(image_file);
Mat img_double;
img.convertTo(img_double, CV64FC3);
```

Then I think img_double should store the image data in DOUBLE, and I tried img_double.depth() it shows as 6, which is correct. However, how do I access that DOUBLE data?? img_double.data is still in uchar* type. Can anybody help me? thanks!

Comment: I think this previous thread answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access data of `img_double` in the following manner.

```
img_double.at<Vec3d>(i, j)[0] -> B
img_double.at<Vec3d>(i, j)[1] -> G
img_double.at<Vec3d>(i, j)[2] -> R
```

so to access pixel values of `img` and `double_img`, you can do something like this

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", img.at<Vec3b>(0, 0)[0], img.at<Vec3b>(0, 0)[1], img.at<Vec3b>(0, 0)[2]);
printf("%f %f %f\n", double_img.at<Vec3d>(0, 0)[0], double_img.at<Vec3d>(0, 0)[1], double_img.at<Vec3d>(0, 0)[2]);
```

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=vec3b#vec) might be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ uses `unsigned char` as the generic data type for a bunch of bytes. 
Hence, having an uchar data pointer in `cv::Mat` avoids to change the declaration of thsi pointer for each type of image, thus avoiding subclassing `cv::Mat` and allowing direct data transfer via `memcpy` or pointer affectation.

Casting is then used to return the data type desired by the user of the library.

Note that OpenCV 2.x provides you th etemplated function `cv::Mat::ptr<type>(ìnt rowIndex)` to obtain a pointer to th ebeginning of a given row.
For example, a pointer to the beginning of row 6 of a grey image of double data type is done by:

```
double *rowPtr = my_mat.ptr<double>(6)
```

Comment: Follow up question, how does it store other data type like "double", while all the data represented by uchar?  Is it "secretly" assign more bytes to the data but kept the data type as uchar?

Comment: Never mind, it was explained in the post stackoverflow.com/a/1735135  mentioned by Shafik Yaghmour

Answer (score 0):

img_data is always uchar (it's bytes - that's all memory is) the image type just keeps track of what type and range you want to think of it as.

Opencv CV is/was a C library at heart so there is no way to have the data actually converted automatically to other types, but you can always just cast it.